# LatLng constructor changes longitude of 180.0 to -180.0

Tags: android, android-location

When creating a new LatLng, if you use 180.0 as the longitude it changes to -180. This behaviour doesn't happen at all with the latitude, 90.0 works just fine.

For example:

```
LatLng blah = new LatLng(-90.0, 180.0);
Log.d(TAG, "blah: " + blah.longitude);
```

Will output:

```
blah: -180.0
```

whereas this works fine:

```
LatLng blah = new LatLng(-90.0, 179.99999999999);
Log.d(TAG, "blah: " + blah.longitude);
```

Output:

```
blah: 179.99999999999
```

I'm thinking this may be due to the precision of doubles, so like actually being 180.00000001 or something like that, but am not sure how to get around that since you can't use strings or big decimals etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation of the [LatLong constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html#LatLng(double,%20double)):

```
 longitude  The point's longitude. This will be normalized to be 
 within -180 degrees inclusive and +180 degrees exclusive.
```

It says `-180 degrees inclusive and +180 degrees exclusive` values from **-180 to 179.999+** are valid means when you put **+180** to the `latlong` it will overflow thus giving you `-180.0` on the result.

On the other hand `179.99999999999` it still valid because it is not more than 180 and will not overflow thus giving you the same value.

Answer (score 3):

-180 and 180 represent the same value of longitude. The [LatLng class](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html#longitude) normalises its properties so that this longitude will always be represented as -180.

This is not a bug, but it does mean you have to be careful because you can't assume the exact representation of the longitude you get out is the same as the one you put in.